# How to merge two tables from two different database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables from two databases.

1. org table from database1.
2. employee table from database2.

How can I merge those tables to get my data.

org table means organization table contains

```
(oid),
oname, 
address 
and some other things (oid is the unique key)
```

employee table contains

```
empid, 
name,
address 
and some other things (empid is the unique key)
```

`oid` is the only common thing in both tables.

I want to merge them and add a filter to both organization and employee name

My problem is both tables are from a different databases.

Comment: Merge how? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve] is worth reading.

Comment: ___oid is the only common thing in both tables.___ Except that `employee` table does not have an `oid` column ??

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: @Dharman in the title they mention `mysqli` So I added that tag which does imply PHP also

Comment: @RiggsFolly The question looks like it meant MySQL database instead of mysqli code.

Comment: @Dharman We may never truely know now